# Dynamically pass columns to COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I need some help with COALESCE.

Syntax: `COALESCE(Col1,Col2,Col3...)` which means every time I will have to write the column names inside as parameters.

**My question is** can we pass the column names dynamically to this function? because number of columns keeps changing in my table.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Sounds like your design might not be normalised. If the number of columns keep changing and the columns represent something similar enough for you to be using `COALESCE` with them. What do `Col1,Col2,Col3` etc. represent?

Comment: Hi Martin - Each column consists of metadata in parent child, but in ragged hierarchy (staircase) format. Due to which there are cells that are NULL, so I am trying to move data towards left and fill empty cells. Now due to changing levels of hierarchy I may different number of columns every time.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ir sounds like you have a bunch of columns and you want to move the values to the left and the `NULL`s to the right.

You can do this by counting the number of non-NULL values before each value and then using `case` statements to assign values.  The following shows the code for four columns:

```
select (case when col1_n = 1 then col1
             when col2_n = 1 then col2
             when col3_n = 1 then col3
             when col4_n = 1 then col4
        end) as col1,
       (case when col2_n = 2 then col2
             when col3_n = 2 then col3
             when col4_n = 2 then col4
        end) as col2,
       (case when col3_n = 3 then col3
             when col4_n = 3 then col4
        end) as col3,
       (case when col4_n = 4 then col4
        end) as col4
from (select t.*,
             (case when col1 is not null then 1 end) as col1_n,
             ((case when col1 is not not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col2 is not null then 1 end)
             ) as col2_n,
             ((case when col1 is not not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col3 is not null then 1 end)
             ) as col3_n,
             ((case when col1 is not not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col4 is not null then 1 end)
             ) as col4_n             
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can see this work at SQL Fiddle ([here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13861)).

If you have a unique `id` for each for, you can also unpivot the data, use `row_number()` and repivot the data.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply. Seems above code is meant for known (fixed) number of columns? The number of columns in my table keeps changing. Can you please tell me if somehow I can pass columns dynamically to COALESCE?

Comment: @user3209759 . . . A table has a fixed number of columns, that is a SQL definition.  It sounds like you might need dynamic SQL or perhaps a redesigned of the application.  An application that adds and removes columns from a table sounds like a bad design.

Comment: My table will have max 20 columns. Out of which lets say I got data for 10 columns, remaining cells will be replaced by NULL. I think I will have to hard code Col1 to col20 in COALESCE instead of passing the columns which are not NULL. I will also see dynamic SQL option as suggested by you. Thanks...

Comment: @user3209759 . . . Then your table has 20 columns.  You can extend the above idea to 20 columns.  It would be much better to have a table with an `id` column and a second column with a value -- a normalized approach to the data.

Comment: I am trying this: SET @Stmt2 = 'Update <databasename>.dbo.<tablename> SET Column'+CAST(@Counter AS VARCHAR)+ '=' +
'COALESCE(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5) where Column'+CAST(@Counter AS VARCHAR)+ '= NULL'
exec(@Stmt2). Its running but not affecting any rows. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write the columns names, Try can do something like this.
This will show you all the rows when all of the columns values are null except for the columns you specified (IgnoreThisColumn1 & IgnoreThisColumn2).

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @query = ISNULL(@query+', ','') + [name] 
                FROM  sys.columns 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourTableName') 
                AND  [name] != 'IgnoreThisColumn1' 
                AND  [name] !=  'IgnoreThisColumn2';

SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM TmpTable WHERE COALESCE('+ @query +') IS NULL';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Result

[image: Result One]

If you don't want rows when all the columns are null except for the columns you specified, you can simply use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `IS NULL`

```
SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM TmpTable WHERE COALESCE('+ @query +') IS NOT NULL';
```

Result

[[image: Result Two[2]]